# Relational database for multiple authors multiple books

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

This is a question my friend was asked in his phone interview with amazon. Design a  relational database to record books where a book can have multiple authors and an author can publish multiple books. He was asked to design the relations ( tables) and the type of each attribute ( whether text, String, etc)
The problem is that they also wanted to be able to search both over Authors names and books title.
I know something like this will not be very efficient:

```
Table Autor 
AutorID AuthorName booksIDs(Text) Example:15, Morris Mano:11,56,234

Table Book
BookID Booktitle AuthorsID(Text) Example: 11:Computer Architecture: 15,34,88
```

What other type is better to use instead of type Text for those attributes here?

Answer (score 2):

The basic third normal form would be something like this that makes use of an intersection table.  Storing comma-separated values in a relational table is always a mistake.

```
CREATE TABLE author (
  authorID integer primary key,
  authorName varchar2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE book (
  bookID integer primary key,
  bookTitle varchar2(100)
);

CREATE TABLE author_book (
  authorID integer,
  bookID   integer,
  constraint pk_author_book primary key( authorID, bookID )
);
```

Now, in reality, you would almost certainly break the author name into a first name, last name, etc. to facilitate searching.  If you are using Oracle, you'd probably create Oracle Text indexes in order to facilitate searching.  And if you're Amazon, you'd potentially want some auxiliary tables created to facilitate searching across attributes in different tables.

Answer (score 2):

I would have done this:

```
Author (AuthorId, AuthorName, etc.)
    PK: AuthorId

Book (BookId, BookName, ISBN, Edition, etc)
    PK: BookId

AuthorBooks (AuthorId, BookId)
    PK: (AuthorId, BookId)
    FK: AuthorId from Author, BookId from Book (thanks to Justin's answer for reminding to add this)
    Another index on BookId to facilitate quick search by BookId.
    Note that the PK index can be used to search on AuthorId.
```

Adding a new book:

1. Insert Into Author
2. Insert Into Book
3. Insert Into AuthorBook

Searching by author name (assuming author name is not unique):

```
SELECT ab.*, b.*
FROM   AuthorBook ab, author a
WHERE  ab.AuthorId IN (SELECT AuthorId
                       FROM   Author 
                       WHERE  AuthorName = ?)
```

and similarly for searching by book title...

Answer (score 1):

You should use a relation table to link authors with books, not put a list of IDs in each table.

```
CREATE TABLE author_book (
    author_id INT,
    book_id INT,
    UNIQUE KEY (author_id, book_id)
);
```

To get the books of an author, or the authors of a book, use a 3-way join, e.g.

```
SELECT BookTitle
FROM Book b
JOIN author_book ab ON b.BooKID = ab.book_id
JOIN Author a ON a.AuthorID = ab.author_id
WHERE AuthorName = 'John Smith';
```